# django - url with automatic slash adding

Tags: django, url, slash

I'm using django admin on my website. When I enter url without slash after admin (http://example.com/admin) I receive 404 error. I thought that django automatically added slash on the end of url. Of course when I enter url ended with slash it works fine. What I am doing wrong, or which settings I have to change. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 10):

Try setting `APPEND_SLASH = True` in *settings.py*.

On second thoughts, I think the default setting is `True`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: Thanks for quick replay. I have put APPEND_SLASH into settings (commonmidelware also is putted) but unfortunately still the same. maybe mod_python has problem with redirecting from 'admin' into 'admin/'?

Comment: I noticed that this happend to all link on my website. not olny admin. When I enter section name not ended with slash, slash didn't add automatically (the difference is that I don't have 404 but it is coused by rule in urls.py)

Comment: Does this happen when you use django's built in webserver or only when you run on Apache?

Comment: Stop using mod_python. I don't know if that's the reason you're having problems, but support for mod_python is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.5 (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/).

Comment: Sriam, I have to check it. Now I only work on mod_python. Thanks. Dominic thanks for info, I will try to change server into mod_wsgi but it depends on my host provider.

Comment: Problem has bessn solved. My mistake in urlsy.py. Thank you for your advieces.

Comment: @lukasz can you tell what was the mistake because am having the same problem

Answer (score 3):

### Don't forget the *CommonMiddleware* in your *settings.py*:

It's important to remember that the `APPEND_SLASH` parameter works in conjunction with the `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'`. So in order for it to work you should have the following in your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

You don't need to add the APPEND_SLASH in your *settings.py* because the default behavior is to redirect URLs that you've typed without and ending slash, for the correct one and as a pattern, you should always write your URLs with an ending slash, like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello_world),
]
```