# how to solve Django POST URL error of APPEND_SLASH

Tags: python, django, url-pattern, form-post

I'm trying get my form POST data onto next page but getting the error

> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/robustSearch/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('search_titles', views.searchTitles, name='search_titles'),
    path('stats/', views.dataStats, name='stats'),

    path('robustSearch/', views.robustSearch, name='robustSearch'),
]
```

And my views.py file

```
def robustSearch(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['titles_file']
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
        counting = df.counts()
    context={
        'counting': counting,
    }
    return render(request, 'result_titles.html', context)
```

and my POST Form file is

```
<form action="robustSearch" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-inline">
     <input type="file" name="titles_file" class="form-control input-sm mr-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>  
</form>
```

anyone can please point out where I'm doing wrong or how can I get this purpose fulfilled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL should be:

```
<form action="/robustSearch/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  …
</form>
```

but it is better to work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<form action="{% url 'robustSearch' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  …
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you lack "/" in your link; this causes that error

in ur urls

```
path('robustSearch/', views.robustSearch, name='robustSearch'),
```

and in ur html

```
action='robustSearch'
```

it should be

```
action='robustSearch/'
```

or you can consult [django - url with automatic slash adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438064/django-url-with-automatic-slash-adding)